# Github - copy github commit history

Tags: github

How can I copy the history of commits A..B from a remote repository? 
Without touching while commit files.

I have tried to use `git rebase`, `git pull --rebase`, `git cherry-pick`...

Comment: "Copy the history of commits without touching the commit files" can mean a lot of things. Instead, tell us what problem you're trying to solve. But you probably want `git fetch`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch). This updates your local repository's view of what the remote looks like. A `git pull` is just a `git fetch` to update your view of what's on the remote plus a `git merge` with those freshly updated remote branches.

Git stores the state of the remote branch within your local repository. This is a huge space saver because they're mostly going to be the same. It uses remote tracking branches like `origin/master`. This is what a repository looks like when you've made two commits to `master`.

```
A - B - C - D [origin/master]
             \
              E - F [master]
```

When you `git fetch` it gets the latest changes from the remote and updates the remote branches. So if someone pushed two changes to master and you do a `git fetch` you'll have this.

```
A - B - C - D - G - H [origin/master]
             \
              E - F [master]
```

Note that none of your local branches changed.

It's totally safe to run `git fetch` as often as you like. You can limit it to fetch only certain commits, but there isn't much point. Just fetch them all.